# Firebase Crash Reporting - NullPointer on toLowerCase

Tags: android

I integrated Firebase Crash Reporting on my Android app and every couple of weeks I am getting this error. Nothing else is specified, only this:

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference

    bsz.d (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:6098)
    bta.run (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1028)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I am having the same problem on that device. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: This is probably an error in the google services codes (the error is thrown by com.google.android.gms). I have the same issue, and my codes don't use toLowerCase() at all.

Comment: I am also not using any lower case method, but till i am getting same error

Comment: Also seeing the same without calling toLowerCase()

Comment: I've just noticed, every single crash occurred on US users on the Nexus 5X, with almost identical specs as @BenjithMathew above (I'm 99.9% sure they're google play reviewers after each new version)[App is primarily Irish users, only US users have been testers]. Perhaps they're automating something strange and GMS is picking it up?

Comment: I'm facing the same just now, same Nexus 5X, Android 6.0.1 and it's Rooted device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems like an error on Google's side. Multiple people are reporting this crash on the exact same device with the exact same region. So it seems Google runs your app on a virtual or automated device and then that device crashes. This device seems to be a Nexus 5x with local us-US and API level 23.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233549

@ssr already specify the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37329979

Comment: for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009734/nullpointer-on-tolowercase-but-i-dont-use-that-method-anywhere

Answer (score 4):

This is internal to Google gms library. It has not been fixed and mostly occurs when Googles Prelaunch Testing happens in Playstore Publish

You can refer and track it here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37329979