# Firebase Crash Report:- String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Can anyone tell me how to fix this crash?[image]

I am unable to find this error in my code because there is not mention which line no has this issue in my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *firebaser here*
This error occurs internally in the Firebase client, because the responses from the server don't match the expected headers in the handshake. My best guess is that there is some system between this client and the Firebase servers that mangles the traffic, resulting in the Firebase client being unable to parse it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009734/nullpointer-on-tolowercase-but-i-dont-use-that-method-anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Error is caused by casting String.toLowerCase on a null object. Post your java.class for more information, or just check where you cast objects to String.toLowerCase and see if they possibly have a null reference. Fixing that should do the job.

Comment: can you tell me which class?

Comment: can you tell me which class about you are talking.