# Getting crash report immediately after uploading app to play store alpha track

Tags: android, google-play

When I upload my APK to the Google Play Store as an alpha release I immediately get the following report in my Firebase Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzdq.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:5111)
       at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzdq$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:143)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

There is no reference to any line in my app source code where the error originates from, but what's more is that there are no test users yet!

Is this being triggered by some automated process in the Google PlayStore which runs my app and some how causes this exception? This still begs the question of where the crash is coming from, considering there's no reference to a line in my app which originates it.

**EDIT**

Since firebase seems to now be providing the sources in the latest version of the database library I now get this crash report immediately after uploading

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketHandshake.verifyServerHandshakeHeaders (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:111)
com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:418)
com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000 (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:47)
com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:143)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

This is now also happening for the open beta track by the way.

Comment: And when you run the download app it does not crash?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009734/nullpointer-on-tolowercase-but-i-dont-use-that-method-anywhere this could be relevant

Comment: As it turns out this is exactly what Google Play does for alpha and beta tracks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_ZEEX1x17k&t=2m10s

Comment: did you find solution, i'm having same error

Comment: @RafaelLima yes I did actually, sorry, I should have reported back. It's essentially a non issue. I've forgotten the links I used to figure this out but essentially Google Play runs auto-mated tests on every APK uploaded to the play store. Sorry I can't provide more details but you don't need to worry about it.