# Crashlytics give crash that is hard to interpret

Tags: android, crashlytics

I go this:

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
           at blm.run + 66(blm.java:66)
           at java.lang.Thread.run + 818(Thread.java:818)
```

But there´s no ref to my app code here

Look at the pic

[image]

How can I know where the `NullPointerException` occurred

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about this. The same issue has been happening to many developers with exact stacktrace. This is a Google lib error. You can find your *crash mates* [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37135148)

**Edit**

> I can't comment yet, so I will post this as a possible solution, but
>   this seems like an error on Google's side. Multiple people are
>   reporting this crash on the exact same device with the exact same
>   region. So it seems Google runs your app on a virtual or automated
>   device and then that device crashes. This device seems to be a Nexus
>   5x with local us-US and API level 23.

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43275377/4370279

Comment: Thanks I got worried there for a minute